# WebView component ignores custom fonts

Tags: python, css, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

PyQt5 has a component called WebView (not QWebView!), that  can load html with its loadHtml method. If the string passed to the method contains a reference to an external font the font is ignored.

Loading html in qml file:

```
mainWebView.loadHtml(article); // mainWebView is the id of a WebView component
```

Preparing html string in py file:

```
with open(CSS_PATH, 'r') as f:
    css_style = f.read()

article = "<html><head><style>%s</style><title>%s</title></head><body>%s</body></html>" % (css_style, article['title'], article['body'])
```

Getting and setting external font in css file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "AvenirNext";
  src: url("AvenirNext-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

html *
{
   color: #e6e6e6;
   font-family: "AvenirNext";
   background-color: #494845;
   margin-left: 14px;
}
```

if I use `font-family: "Courier New"` in CSS the font works fine. Only if I get some font from a folder, it's ignored. I put the ttf file both in the app root folder AND in a folder where the css file resides, just in case.
Link to the component:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtwebview-webview.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtwebview-webview.html#loadHtml-method):

> #### void loadHtml(string html, url baseUrl)
>
> Loads the specified html content to the web view.
>
> This method offers a lower-level alternative to the url property,
>   which references HTML pages via URL.
>
> **External objects such as stylesheets or images referenced in the HTML
>   document should be located relative to baseUrl**. For example, if html
>   is retrieved from http://www.example.com/documents/overview.html,
>   which is the base URL, then an image referenced with the relative url,
>   diagram.png, should be at http://www.example.com/documents/diagram.png

The .css, .js or any external element will be relative to baseUrl which is the second parameter of `setHtml()`. So the solution is to pass it the url of a fictitious file that should be in the local folder.

**main.py**

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQml

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    CSS_PATH = "styles.css"
    with open(os.path.join(dir_path, CSS_PATH), 'r') as f:
        css_style = f.read()
        article = {"title": "title1", "body": "<H1> Body"}
        article = "<html><head><style>%s</style><title>%s</title></head><body>%s</body></html>" % (css_style, article['title'], article['body'])
        baseUrl = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(dir_path, 'index.html'))
        engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("article", article)
        engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("baseUrl", baseUrl)
    qml_filename = os.path.join(dir_path, 'main.qml')
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml_filename))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWebView 1.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    WebView{
        id: mainWebView
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    Component.onCompleted: mainWebView.loadHtml(article, baseUrl)
}
```

I'm assuming that the project has the following structure:

```
|-- AvenirNext-Regular.ttf
|-- main.py
|-- main.qml
`-- styles.css
```